# AngularJS within a style element not working

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use angular js bindings within a style element yet it doesn't seem to work.  Is this a bug and is there a better way to do this?

```html
<style ng-repeat="test in styles">
.test {
    background-color: {{ test.backgroundColor }};
    display: {{ test.display }};
    width: {{ test.width }};
    height: {{ test.height }};
    }
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cmsanche/PpyVn/

Comment: what is this supposed to accomplish? if you have more than one array item you will have 2 definitions for the same class name

Comment: The fiddle was just an example that angularjs wasn't parsing the style element.  I could easily add something like .test_{{test.id}} to make each class name unique.  I was working on a project where I needed to position a lot of images based on coordinates from a db.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think Angular parses style elements. You probably want to use the ngStyle directive:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.module.ng.$compileProvider.directive.ngStyle

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0rc10.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-init="styles=[{backgroundColor: 'red', width:'100px', height: '100px', display: 'block'}]">

<div ng-repeat="test in styles" ng-style="test">
.test {
    background-color: {{ test.backgroundColor }};
    display: {{ test.display }};
    width: {{ test.width }};
    height: {{ test.height }};
    }
</div>
</html>
```

Plunker (like jsFiddle, but more Angular-friendly) [**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/n70DQw?p=preview)

Comment: I would like to find a way of doing this in a style tag in order to give `a:hover` some dynamic styles... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This now works in newer versions of Angular.

Here http://jsfiddle.net/PpyVn/4/ is the OPs fiddle with 1.0 replaced with 1.3.0-rc.3.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.3/angular.min.js"></script>
```